# Copy live CD to RAM on boot

Tags: boot, boot-loader, livecd

OK, so I've put together a live CD which uses isolinux as the bootloader. Any idea what magical option or switch I need to use to make it copy the compressed filesystem to RAM before mounting it? (Not the entire CD, just the compressed filesystem image.)

Comment: Check how [SLAX](http://www.slax.org/) does it (depending on kernel parameter `copy2ram`)